# What does difference in the number of dots in Fitted vs Residuals plot mean?

Tags: residuals, fitting

What does difference in the number of dots in Fitted vs Residuals plot mean?

Like in the below plots of two different models:

Model 1:
[image]

Model 2:
[image]

The length of `fitted()` of both models is the same, but why does it seem that Model 2 has a lot more predictions?

Also does this kind of difference tell anything about the goodness of fit? Is more dots necessarily better?

---

The models are:

```
model1 <- glm(formula = cancer ~ exposure + skin + gender, family = binomial, 
    data = dta)
model2 <- glm(formula = cancer ~ exposure + age * trt * skin + gender, 
    family = binomial, data = dta)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is probably some overplotting going on in the plot which appears to have too few dots. Try plotting the plot "by hand" and then add some `jitter()` and you will be able to visually confirm that.

Comment: Is overplotting bad or does it just mean that there are many predictions getting the same predicted value and the same residual?

Comment: The latter.  It is only a problem for the visual investigations of the plot. I guess it is in the nature of your data, that only limited numbers occur and thus equal predictions and residuals are frequent in model1. It is not a problem per we.